# How to override composer problem detection when using Symfony command line

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, composer-php

My host updated composer version ( 2.2 ) without updating php version ( 7.0.33 ).

When I run `composer [command]`, I get this error:

> Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for PHP <7.2.5 and you are running 7.0.33-0+deb9u12, please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.

I don't have the option to downgrade composer (`composer self-update --2.2` give me the same ) and this php version is locked.

So I decided to use `/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar [command]` instead and it works. I think `php /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar` will work too.

I'm using Symfony 4 and now I need to deploy my application. But when I try `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` composer detect issues because my dependencies require a higher php version than defined in var

> PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.5". You are running 7.0.33-0+deb9u12. in /var/www/vhosts/client-name/httpdocs/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

**First question:** Why composer is called when I try to update my database using doctrine CLI?

**What I tried**

I run `composer config platform.php 7.0.33`
Some of my dependencies are now too new, so I'm trying to downgrade them to the latest major version.

I changed the version of PHP and in libraries in the "require" section and I run `/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar update --with-dependencies` ( because just `composer` cause me problems )
It doesn't work for doctrine which need PHP 7.1 and I don't want to go back to doctrine 1 ( doctrine 2.0 was released in 2010 )

**Second question:** Do you have any suggestion? I don't see an immediate solution

Comment: Did you try to download and use composer binary at the version you want?

Comment: @qdequippe no I can't but just after thinking about it all afternoon and posting this question, I found the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I had to upgrade PHP by running:

$ `brew unlink php@7.1`

$ `brew link php@8.1`

Hope that can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem than me, you may need to call symfony command using PHP binaries directly:

`/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php bin/console d:s:u --dump-sql`